# How to show that the limit of this partial sum is the supreme

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Let $A\subset(0,\infty)$ be a countable subset and $\mathcal{A}=\{B\subset A: |B|<\infty\}$. Define

$$\sum_{a\in A} a:=\sup_{B\in \mathcal{A}}\sum_{b\in B} b.$$

Define $a_n: \mathbb{N}\to A$ by $n\to a_n$ be a bijection. Show that $\sum_{a\in A} a=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$.

---

My idea is to define the partial sum by $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k$. Clearly, this sequence is increasing and then $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n$ exists and it should be $\sup\{S_n: n\ge 1\}$.

But I am stuck on how to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} S_n=\sum_{a\in A} a$.

Comment: Prove that each side is $\le$ the other.

Comment: @geetha290krm One side is clear. I can show that $\sup\{S_n: n\ge 1\}\le \sum_{a\in A} a$ (since that is sup of partial sum of each finite sum). But how about the other side? It seems that we do not use the condition that "A is countable"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $B \in \mathcal A$. The elements of $B$ can be written in form $a_{n_1},a_{n_2},...,a_{n_j}$ (with distinct $n_i's$). If $n > \max \{n_1,n_2,...,n_j\}$ then $\sum_{b \in B} b\le S_n\le \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty }a_k$. Take supremum over $B$.